# Preview Google Slides/PowerPoint

Tags: java, saas

Is there any way to preview Google slides/MS powerpoint which are hosted somewhere like Google drive or external storage, in a SaaS java application?

For example, adding new content in web application by business users, copying a link of powerpoint/google slides, which will generate a preview of this file.